# Find a normal subgroup $N$ of $(\Bbb Z_{10}, +)$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

I am to find a normal subgroup $H$ of $(\Bbb Z_8, +)$ and a normal subgroup $N$ of $(\Bbb Z_{10}, +)$.

The definition of a subgroup is given by:

> A *normal* subgroup $F$ of the group $G$ has $gfg^{-1}\in F$ for $\forall g\in G$ and $\forall f\in F$. Every subgroup of an *abelian* group is normal since we have that $gfg^{-1}=gg^{-1}f=ef=f$.

And the following theorem defines a subgroup:

> The subgroup $F$ of the group $G$ is normal if and only if one of the following conditions are met:
>
> 1. $aF=Fa$ for $\forall a\in G$
> 2. $F$ is equal to its conjugate, that is, $aFa^{-1}=F$ for $\forall a\in G$
> 3. $F$ is invariant under all inner automorphics of $G,$ *that is,* $aFa^{-1}=F$ for $\forall a\in G$

Now, I've solved the first part of the question by writing:

> $\Bbb Z_8$ is an abelian group since it is a product of abelian groups, and also because the center $Z(G)$ of $G$ is equal to $G$. Thus, any subgroup of $\Bbb Z_8$ is normal. Therefore, we choose an arbitrary subgroup of $Z_8$ as $H$.
> $$H=\{0,2,4,6\}.$$

Comment: The $H$ you defined is not a subgroup. Also, $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ is abelian.

Comment: Oh, I seem to have misunderstood, I am still confused as to if I should use modulus 8 or not. Is the group $H$ I defined now after editing a subgroup?

Comment: Condition 1, as written, is a tautology; do you mean "$aF=Fa$" instead?

Comment: Yes, thank you, I didn't notice

Comment: When you say "$\Bbb Z_8$ is an abelian group since it is a product of abelian groups, and also because the center $Z(G)$ of $G$ is equal to $G$.", the first reason is circular, and the other is in reverse. The only way to write $\Bbb Z_8$ as a product of groups is if one of the factors is $\Bbb Z_8$ itself. And the center is the whole group because the group is abelian, not the other way around (how else would you show what the center is, other than checking that each element commutes with every other element?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each group $G$ is a normal subgroup of itself. The trivial subgroup is also normal in every group.

However, I'm guessing you're looking for a nontrivial, proper subgroup that is normal for each $\Bbb Z_8$ and $\Bbb Z_{10}$.

It is useful to note (and rather easy to show) that these two groups are abelian, so any subgroup of each is normal in that group.

For $\Bbb Z_8$, take the subgroup $\langle [2]_8\rangle$ generated by $[2]_8$; for $\Bbb Z_{10}$, consider $\langle [2]_{10}\rangle$.